# Possibe data corruption in x-ray room

Tags: networking, lan, database, data-transfer, fingerprint

I built a small fingerprint ID system for a lab. Registration is done at a reception and identification at 2 other points. One point is the x-ray room

The problem: Identification often seems to fail at the x-ray room.

The entire place is cabled using standard UTP.

My question: Is this failure to do with the x-ray room's radiation and stuff?

More info:

1. I've tested the WAN/LAN speeds using a ping with the server.
2. The software uses VB6 + Access.
3. With the Access database on the PC at the x-ray room, the failure rate is lower.

Thanks for any suggestions on how to get about this.

Comment: "With the Access database on the PC at the x-ray room, the failure rate is lower."  Where was it before?

Comment: @Breakthrough the database is on another PC that acts as a server. This server is not in the x-ray room. When identification fails, we copy the DB to the local machine in the x-ray room and when the system is restarted, it seems to work. But using the x-ray machine continuously as a server only makes it worse.

Answer (score 0):

For the networking part.

Any kind of data errors caused by radiation(eg. bit-flip) will be caught by checksum or higher layers so its highly unlikely that xray is affecting the network in any way which causes fingerprint ID to fail.

What device are you using for scanning prints?

Perhaps you can try interchanging the scanning devices at  2 points where you are scanning, to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'm using the (terrible, excuse me) Suprema BioMini. Interchanging devices hasn't served. Even tried using the x-ray room PC as a server. It only got worse.

Comment: in that case it is perhaps affecting the functionality of sensor in the scanner.

Comment: I'd have agreed with your statement. But sometimes even if the scan succeeds, the identification from the database fails.

Comment: i would say scan succeeding doesnt mean the device scanned the actual fingerprint accurately, well that is just my guess

Comment: +1 for this... I thought the same. But now my issue is what to do about this? In general aren't there scanners within x-ray rooms?